# Change UIButton background images randomly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to change the background image of a `UIButton` randomly. I have some images (5) that I want to switch between randomly as background images for a `UIButton`. How can I implement this? Please help me out with this problem.

Comment: `[btn setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];` set Using this but what's the logic you are looking ?

Comment: Actually i am moving button randomly on that i would like to change the button background images randomly.... when ever i will click butoon i need to increase ivalue depends upon images i will change i value increase how can i implement dis..

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this

```
NSInteger randomNumber =  arc4random_uniform(5); // random number, either 0,1,2,3 or 4
UIImage *randomImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%u.png",randomNumber]];

//UIButton *myButton;
[myButton setBackgroundImage:randomImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Alternate solution that perhaps is easier for you to understand

```
NSInteger randomNumber =  arc4random_uniform(5); // random number, either 0,1,2,3 or 4
UIImage *randomImage;

switch (randomNumber) {
    case 0:
        randomImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img0.png"];
        break;
    case 1:
        randomImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"];
        break;
    case 2:
        randomImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"];
        break;
    case 3:
        randomImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"];
        break;
    case 4:
        randomImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img4.png"];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
//UIButton *myButton;
[myButton setBackgroundImage:randomImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

For future reference; you should NOT ask question where you more or less ask for someone to solve your problems for you. Include what you have tried even if you only have pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  //give Your Image name is P0.png, P1.png, P2.png,P3.png, P4.png
    int r = arc4random() % 5;
    NSString *strImg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"P%@.png",r];
    UIImage *Image;
    Image = [UIImage imageNamed:strImg];
    [YourButton setBackgroundImage:Image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create Array Of Images Name 
NSMutableArray *arrayOfImagesName=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"img1.png",@"img2.png",@"img3.png",nil];


//choose random image name from array
    int rndNumber=arc4random() % [arrayOfImagesName count];

//set image to the button 
    [myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayOfImagesName objectAtIndex:rndNumber]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Static int variable set it's value to 0 initially. when button tap occurs increase value of that variable by 1 and pass that variable as argument to switch case. write code to change the image on each case and when count of static variable reaches 5 reset it to 0 again.

```
// write this at top of implementation file
static int count = 0;
```

// then on button click

```
 {

 UIImage *image;

 count++;
 switch(count)
 {
    case 1:
           image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic1.png"];
           break;
    case 2:
           image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic2.png"];
           break;
    case 3:
           image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic3.png"];
           break;
    case 4:
           image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic4.png"];
           break;   
    case 5:
           image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic5.png"];
           count = 0;
           break;
 }

  [button setBackgroundImage: image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```